# I am seeing that sls deploy is auto-creating an IAM role for my Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I don't have`iamrolestatements` property in my serverless.yml. But I am seeing that `sls deploy` is auto-creating an IAM role for my Lambda functions. The permissions that the role has are:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogStream"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<acc id>:log-group:/aws/lambda/servicename-stage-functionname:*"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow"
            },
            {
                "Action": [
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:<acc id>:log-group:/aws/lambda/servicename-stage-functionname:*"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I wonder how is this so ? Why is the role getting auto created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default role created by Serverless framework. This role gives your Lambda functions permission to create and write to CloudWatch logs.

The policies you add by using `iamRoleStatements` is just merged into this role's policy.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/